# Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks breaks passwordless SSH to localhost (for hadoop)

Tags: macos, ssh, osx-mavericks, hadoop

Sorry if this sounds like a repeat, but I'm fairly sure it's specifically Mac OS X 10.9 related, it works fine for me on my 10.8 machine. I've done everything identically, as usual:

```
$:~ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" $:~ cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But yet it always demands a password now on 10.9. Apparently, it's not accepting the public key:

> % ssh -v localhost OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011 ...
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue:
>   publickey,keyboard-interactive debug1: Next authentication method:
>   publickey debug1: Offering RSA public key:
>   /Users/edwardbrowne/.ssh/id_rsa debug1: Authentications that can
>   continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive

Note that when it's working on 10.8, the line after "Offering RSA public key:" is like so:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
```

But in 10.9 it *doesn't* accept it, it just moves on to the next authentication method. In both cases, the "id_rsa" file seems identical:

```
% ls -l id_rsa -rw------- 1 edwardb staff 1679 Mar 30 10:16 id_rsa %
```

So why does the server accept the offer of the public key in one case, but not in the other?

Thanks, and cheers - Ed

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that both /etc/ssh_config and /etc/sshd_config are the same (on the 10.9 machine and the 10.8 machine.) I copied them over, and restarted sshd, but no change.

Answer (score 1):

If you get any error remove (or change to something else) ~/.ssh/known_hosts and retry connecting to localhost.

Comment: No, that doesn't have any effect (I can't see why it would.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and it turned out that I had too many readwrite permissions in my `.ssh` directory. I ran `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`, to ensure that the `.ssh` directory permissions looked like this:

`drwx------   15 username    staff      510 Jun  2 01:08 .ssh`

And then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using a dsa key instead. I already had one so I just added it to  authorized_keys

```
$cat id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

If you don't have a dsa key, you could try creating one to see if it works:

```
$ssh-keygen -t dsa -P ""
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't accept id_dsa from 10.9 either.  See: ...debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/edward/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /Users/edward/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
%

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem (also for use by hadoop) on 0SX 10.11.
I saw that in the /var/log/system.log I had:

```
sshd[22163]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory
```

I did:

```
chmod g-w $HOME
chmod o-w $HOME
```

And `ssh localhost` started working without a password.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried...

```
ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I had a similar issue with OS X 10.10 and that fixed it for me.

Comment: You should explain what this does and how it answers the question.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, but that doesn't change anything (I'm with @david-richerby, too, I'd like to know what this might do to fix the problem.)